# How shall i read the data which is in [form]?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, key

```
Array
(
    [i_id] => 0
    [f_tok] => _p9kmWKZaplimWSZeJlymVKZQplEmUwH7AfkE~xB5BsXLZtBnZ8HmQefnw!!
    [form] => [{"name":"Incident.Threads","value":"asd","required":true},{"name":"Incident.Product","value":188,"required":false},{"name":"Incident.Category","value":142,"required":false},{"name":"Contact.Name.First","value":"asd","required":true}]
)
```

This is received through the `$_POST`. Using `print_r` I have printed this data out of `$_POST`.

How can I get data which is in `[form] => [{.....}]`?

Answer (score 1):

That's a JSON string, you can decode it into an array and then take it from there.

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['form']));
```

Comment: Hanky, Thanks . I got the solution.